# PHP array_diff_assoc in same variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array in one variable $collection

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    0 => 40
    1 => 39
    2 => 43
    3 => 41
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    0 => 40
  ]
]
```

Is there any way to perform `array_diff_assoc` in one variable instead of this `array_diff_assoc($collection[0], $collection[1])`.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With splat operator (`...`) you can:

```
$a = [
    [40, 39, 43, 41],
    [40],
];

print_r(array_diff_assoc(...$a));
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/pMV7V).